# presentViewControllerAsSheet shows like window

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a window `DeviceNotFound` in my `AppDelegate` class.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    let deviceNotFoundWindowController = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "DeviceNotFoundWindowController") as! DeviceNotFoundWindowController

    func test() {
         if let loadDataVc = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "LoadDataViewController") as? LoadDataViewController
         {
             self.deviceNotFoundWindowController.contentViewController!.presentViewControllerAsSheet(loadDataVc)
         }
    }
}
```

When I call `test` function to show another `ViewController` as Sheet, it displaying like window. My `DeviceNotFound` window not blocked. I can move it:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, found issue. Because my initial `window controller != deviceNotFoundWindowController` that i get from nib.